# Xcode:Reachability on additional view controller using storyboard

Tags: uiviewcontroller, popup, storyboard, reachability

My app has 3 view controllers. VC#3(*Sponsor) takes the user to my website & so I am trying to implement Reachability for this VC. I added System Configuration framework & Apples Reachability .H & .M files to the project. Disabled ARC for Reachability .M file & VC#3 .M file. The project B&R fine, but I still do not get the pop up alert when disconnected from internet.  I imported Reachability.h to VC#3 also. What am I missing?

VC#3(*Sponsor).M

```
#import "Sponsor.h"
#import "ViewController.h"



@interface Sponsor ()  

@end

@implementation Sponsor

 -(void)viewDidLoad {
[webview loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL      
 URLWithString:@"http://opticertificationprep.webs.com/"]]];


 }


 - (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
 {
     self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
     if (self) {
         // Custom initialization
     }
     return self;
 }

  -(IBAction)home:(id)sender{



 }

 - (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
 {
     // Releases the view if it doesn't have a superview.
     [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];

     // Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
 }

 - (BOOL) hasInternet {
      Reachability *reach = [Reachability      
 reachabilityWithHostName:@"www.opticertificationprep.webs.com"];
     NetworkStatus internetStats = [reach currentReachabilityStatus];

     if (internetStats == NotReachable) {
         UIAlertView *alertOne = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error"     
 message:@"Check Your Internet Connection" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Okay"   
 otherButtonTitles:nil]; 
         [alertOne show];
         [alertOne release];
 }
    
      return YES;

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

For anyone with same problem. I was missing this bit of code in the the .M file. Once I added it my pop up alert works great.

```
`
 -(void)viewDidLoad {

     {

         [super viewDidLoad];
         [self hasInternet];

     }
```

`